# Google recaptcha doesn't work in IIS

Tags: c#, html, ajax, wcf, recaptcha

I have implemented Google recaptcha in my WCF service and I want to verify it from a mobile device. I have tested it in local host and it doesn't work when I publish and deployed in IIS.
Any suggestions?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more information, what version of IIS server? Try to make some validations to see what is the problem, but for now:

- You add the reference on your website to library/bin/Release/Recaptcha.dll?
- Maybe reCaptcha is accesible from the server you deployed to? if the
  answer is no, you have to add a proxy.